# Why are vector coordinates different to matrix coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm starting a Linear Algebra course and I'm a bit confused.

Say we have a vector
$x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$, and another vector $y = \begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

When we have a matrix composed of the two vectors, instead of saying $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&y_1\\
x_2&y_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

we say that the first column corresponds to $x_1$, and the second corresponds to $x_2$ so
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&x_2\\
y_1&y_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Maybe I misunderstood something, but I feel like this is a bit confusing to me, may someone explain to me how this works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends on your definition of the matrix. What is the purpose for the matrix?

Comment: Well I've seen vectors being put in a set, and then converted from the set to a matrix. But then the concept of free variables confused me with that, since when we put the equations into parametric vector form we label them $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ based on the column position and not the rows. (i.e. if the second column does not have a pivot position, you say $x_2$ is free) @Andrei

Answer (score 1):

This just depends on context and definitions. Both are feasible in the right context:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces

Answer (score 0):

There are contexts where matrices can be considered to be a vector of vectors. There are two types of vectors: row vectors and column vectors. A matrix can be viewed as either column vector where all the elements are row vectors, or a row vectors where all the elements are column vectors.

Thus $\left[\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \cr x_2 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \cr y_2 \end{bmatrix} \right]$ can be considered to represent $\begin{bmatrix} x_1& y_1 \cr x_2& y_2 \end{bmatrix}$. If we're representing the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \cr y_1& y_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then the we should write $x$ and $y$ as row vectors: $x = [x_1, x_2]$, $y=[y_1,y_2]$, so that $\begin{bmatrix} x\cr y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1& x_2 \cr y_1& y_2 \end{bmatrix}$. It looks to me that your textbook and/or instructor is failing to distinguish between row and column vectors and treating $[x_1, x_2]$ and $\begin{bmatrix} x_1\cr x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ as interchangeable, either out of ignorance, laziness, or a belief that doing so would overly confuse students (and in doing so, confusing at least one student anyway).